# Run 3 python functions concurrently then add their values together

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am generating the coefficients for x, y and z. I want to run the generating functions simultaneously (as they take a while), then once all generated, merge the coefficients together. My ideal code will be a bit like this:

```
#generated in parallel
  x = generate_x()
  y = generate_y()
  z = generate_z()

merged = x + y + z
```

I don't want to wait for each generate function before I start generating the next one, but I also need them all to finish before I merge them at the end. How can this be done?

Comment: Take a look at the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) from the standard library.

Comment: Or maybe `Threading`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "concurrent" library to easily implement concurrency in your code.

```
from concurrent import futures

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
    results = [exe.submit(generate_x), exe.submit(generate_y), exe.submit(generate_z)]
    sum_coeffs = sum(result.result() for result in futures.as_completed(results))
```

You can store all threads in a list like this while they are running and then access the thread when it's completed by using the `as_completed()` method in the futures library.
After that access the stored result in the completed thread with the `result()` method and sum them all up.

Look here to learn more about the [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).